# Homogeneous linear ordinary differential equations of high order (order >= 2) with continuous coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a linear ordinary differential equation of, say, order 2. Something like:

$$y''(x) + \sin(x) \cdot y(x)' + (x^2 + \sin(x)^3) \cdot y(x) = 0$$

Say, we don't have any given solution to the equations.
Say, also, that the coefficients, are continuous, but not constant and not polynomials. Do we have a method for finding the base functions for the corresponding homogeneous function?

I ask this, since, in every ODE course/book that I have looked, it is stated that there is a solution (uniqueness and existence theorem).

It is also taught, that in the non-homogeneous case the solution is: $$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x)$$

However, it is never mentioned how to find this $y_h(x)$ in a general case of general continuous coefficients (Unless I am missing something?).

It is also not stated that there is no general analytic method and only approximations would work.
(since, I guess using series approximation would help?)

Why is it not mentioned that there is no method for the general case?
Or am I missing something and there is a method?
If there is any explanation or maybe even recommended online source I would be grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Past a certain degree of complexity in the equations, qualitative analysis is more efficient and fruitful than searching for explicit solutions. The closest you can get are asymptotics or power series methods such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method

Comment: A perusal of [**Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers. Asymptotic Methods and Perturbation Theory**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0387989315) by Bender/Orszag (1978/1999) will help a lot with what you are asking. I had a course out of this book 39 years ago, and one of the things I recall is that it's often easier to analyze asymptotic and qualitative behavior of a solution by directly working with the differential equation than by working with an integral expression for a solution (even when a closed form evaluation exists) or a series expansion of a solution.

Comment: Thank you both very much for the links and clarification